# How to make BootStrap-DatePicker to Submit Form on Enter key press

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've a page which is containing the first UI element as `Bootstrap datetimepicker4` along with few input fields and  2 submit buttons: 1 is for validating the form and redirecting to next page and the other is the `Back button`.

When I open the application on web, and focus is on datetimepicker input, and click on `Next` button it is submitting the form.

But when I open the website in iPhone, and focus is on datetimepicker, and when I click on `Go button` in iPhone keypad it is not submitting the form.
My requirement here is to submit the form when I hit Go button in iPhone.

I am using the below scripts in my page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my view:

```
     <div class="input-group date jsdate">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    <input name="submit" class="btn btn-primary order-2" type="submit" value="Next">
    <input name="back" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 " type="submit" value="Back" formnovalidate formaction="BackToContactInfo?tabId=@Model.TabId">
```

and the script for datetimepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('.jsdate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
        maxDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

I observed that in datetimepicker in enter keypress there are two events which are firing: `e.preventdefault` and `e.stoppropagation`.
So as per my requirement, when an enter is pressed instead of stopping the propagation,I want to submit the form.
So is there any setting to continue the propagation pls help me.

Comment: Where is your "Go" button in code?

Comment: When I open my website in iPhone then Go button will be in iPhone keypad

Answer (score 0):

Your "Go" button from iOS device will have same key code as "Enter" button so you can detect the click event fired on that button as bellow,

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) { // for enter key
   // Do your form submission call here
  }
});
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: but, what if i enter invalid date and press enter?? So what I want is bootstrap datepicker is doing preventdefault and stoppropagation in enter key press. 
So can you provide me some solution to stop process those evnts instead of stopping

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#" id="form">
   <div class="input-group date jsdate" style="position: relative;">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date">
       <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
   </div>
   <input name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary order-2" type="submit" value="Next">
   <input name="back" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 " type="submit" value="Back" formnovalidate formaction="BackToContactInfo?tabId=@Model.TabId">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
 $('#date').keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         $('#form').submit();
     }
 })
```

Please consider that to use jquery submit method you have to change the name of your **Submit** button.

Comment: Made necessary edits to the question, pls check it and if possible pls provide me some solution.

Comment: if you focus on datepicker hit on Go this will submit the form. I think your problem is that after choosing the date the focus is not on the input. is that right?

Comment: yes, the focus is not on the datepicker, also I made necessary changes to my question pls review.